# Can't install fglrx on Kernel 3.11.0-12

Tags: drivers, kernel, 13.10, fglrx

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 on a Sony Vaio laptop. I tried to install the newest `fglrx` driver from the [cchtml.com guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide) but no matter which version I use (13.4 or even 13.9) the installation of the generated `.deb`s fails with this message:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-12-generic (x86_64)
```

This seems to be a *confirmed* bug [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/859101). Currently I'm running the Radeon SI driver but I really need some 3D acceleration. What is there I can do to install any version of `fglrx` correctly or to speed up the bug-fixing-process? How long does the fixing of these bugs usually take?

---

I just discovered this [patch for the driver](https://github.com/kolasa/fglrx-13.152). But I have no idea how to apply it. [The explanation of the developer](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=847#c4) is not clear to me. Anyone has any idea what I need to do to compile this patched version of the driver myself?

Comment: Can't answer on how long it will take to be fixed, but I had the same issue with Kubuntu 13.10 and Catalyst 13.4. Went to 13.04 as a fallback and it was okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in the amd changelog on the [official download page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx) it says:

> Resolved Issues:
>
> - [387659] Fixes X crash when kill X server with Xserver 1.13 and above

So I downloaded and installed the newest version (13.11 beta) and it worked. I still have some issues with applications and the x-server crashing, but the driver installed correctly and the `deb`s-build was successful.